# Shorten text in every second paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am writting a Jquery for a Wordpress website. Changing html is out of the question only CSS or Jquery so if there is a solution for my problem with those two it would be great.

I have several divs on my site:

```
<div class="wf-cell wf-span-4 wpb_column column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element textblock_grey">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h4> header here </h4>
            <p> image with link here </p>
            <p> TEXT HERE</p>
            <p> link here </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wan't to shorten the text in the second p element in textblock_grey div. I already tried writting:

```
if ($(".textblock_grey p:nth-child(2)").text().length >60) {
    $(".textblock_grey p:nth-child(2)").text().substring(0, 60);
}
```

but it doesn't work I suspect it just measures the length of all the p elements in all divs on my site not for each div one by one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never actually set the text:

```
$(".textblock_grey p:nth-child(2)").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().substring(0, 60);
});
```

Comment: how can I extend on top of that so that only text inside p gets shortened but other elements like `<a>` are left intact?

Comment: Also can you explain why is it necessary to use `return`?

Comment: @LazyPeon -- `return` is necessary because `.text()` takes a parameter (the text to be set) - so we use a function and return that text.